# Mounting external hard drive in 11.10

Tags: usb, mount, external-hdd

I'm trying to mount an external Hitachi hard drive. Supposedly it's USB 3.0 and backwards compatible with 2.0.

I can see it with lsusb (it's "SimpleTech"):

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:00dd Microsoft Corp. Comfort Curve Keyboard 2000 V1.0
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 011: ID 4971:1013 SimpleTech
```

Additionally, the system appears to see it's a "high speed USB device", and it uses ehci_hcd. From "dmesg | grep -i usb", plugging in and out a few times:

```
[1914076.788026] usb 1-8: new high speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
[1914118.992058] usb 1-8: reset high speed USB device number 9 using ehci_hcd
[1914466.772118] usb 1-8: USB disconnect, device number 9
[1914478.188029] usb 1-7: new high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[1914516.944023] usb 1-7: reset high speed USB device number 10 using ehci_hcd
[1914828.148003] usb 1-7: USB disconnect, device number 10
[1914832.184073] usb 1-7: new high speed USB device number 11 using ehci_hcd
```

Also, it shows up as /dev/sde. However, "sudo fdisk -l" doesn't show it, gparted doesn't see it, and "sudo parted /dev/sde" gives me "No such device or address".

I know the hard drive works, because I can use it in Mac OS X 10.6 (it's formatted FAT32).

What can I do?

Comment: I don't know if it's any different from gParted, but I usually use the Disk Utility to mount something that hasn't automatically?

Comment: James, Disk Utility is a Mac OS X application, and I'm looking for a Linux solution.

Comment: ...well if I type in 'Disk Utility' in the dash,it comes up. It's certainly a program that comes with Ubuntu 11.10 by default. It's made by Red Hat.

Comment: Is it visible in Nautilus as unmounted?

Comment: Can you mount it manually?

Comment: I plugged it into my Ubuntu box, and it shows up with Disk Utility (DU). DU sees the partitions, though it doesn't recognize the filesystems on the partitions; this is odd as one is FAT32. I currently have a working solution using Ubuntu on Virtualbox on a Mac, but if I ever need to get this working with Linux, I'll try reformatting with DU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James suggested, using Disk Utility seems to be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with a new Hitachi external 2T drive as well.

The drive is detected properly with Mac OS X "Lion" (10.7.2). The disk has a MBA partition table with a single NTFS 2.0TB partition.

I found a hint that black-listing the "uas" driver would help.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11334979&postcount=17

I tried a "rmmod uas", but this didn't seem to help. After a reboot, the drive seems to be detected and working properly.